# What is the "delivery mode" in AMQP?

Tags: amqp

I understand that 2 options are available:

- "Non-persistent"
- "Persistent"

But what does this actually mean?

"Non-persistent" as in : the AMQP fabric will try to deliver the message if there are no consumers, the message will be dropped?

"Persistent" as in : AMQP will retry the message until a consumer accepts it??

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Messages marked as 'persistent' that are delivered to 'durable' queues will be logged to disk.  Durable queues are recovered in the event of a crash, along with any persistent messages they stored prior to the crash.

Comment: I do not understand why you can declare an Exchange durable. And on the other side you "could"!? declare a queue that "corresponds" to that Exchange nondurable? Or for example if you would declare a Exchange NONDURABLE but a queue durable, and there would be a crash. Could I recover that durable queue in the nondurable exchange? @alexis

Comment: "durability" only means the Exchange or Queue will survive a server restart.. This does not mean the messages being stored in a durable queue will survive... That would _also_ require a message level property `.deliveryMode = 2`. (I just tested these cases)

Answer (score 24):

`delivery_mode` in AMQP determines if message will be stored on disk after broker restarts.  You can mark messages as persistent - by seting `delivery_mode property = 2` when you publish message 
for instance in PHP (PECL AMQP extension):

```
$exchange->publish($text, $routingKey, null, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
```

You would also need to declare queue as durable (or it will be dropped after broker stops)

```
$queue->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
```

Comment: Will the continue to be stored on disk even after they are processed? Or is it only a guarantee that they will be persisted until they get processed?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the delivery mode will tell RabbitMQ if it’s allowed to keep the message in memory when the message is placed in a queue (non-persistent) or if it must store the message on disk first (persistent).