# Make a Rabbit message persistent in PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm using http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php to use Rabbit on my server.
I have problem to make my messages persistent. I'm setting the exchange and the queue as `AMQP_DURABLE`, but after the server is restarted the queues are empty. It looks like the messages aren't saved to the disk.

I'm publishing my messages with: http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpexchange.publish.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the message as durable. What you're doing now is to only set the exchange and queue to durable, which is exactly what is happening.

So to save your messages to disk you need to set the delivery_mode to `2`. Which means just that, `durable`.

Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344022/what-is-the-delivery-mode-in-amqp) to see it in action (code shamelessly copied from @Grzegorz Motyl's answer):

```
$exchange->publish($text, $routingKey, null, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
```